# mapping json to Java object

Tags: java, json, coffeescript, mapping

I send my data from client like this

```
$.ajax
  type: "POST"
  url: "/plan"
  dataType: "json"
  ContentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  data: plan
  success:(data) ->
    alert "Save Plan Succeesfully"
```

In java code, I have class Plan which has same fields with data in json. So now, I want to mapping from data(json) to may Plan object in Java code.
Help me!

Comment: What architecture are you using?  This is extremely easy with Spring MVC but it all depends on your back end.

Comment: Not Spring. I'm using Slim3 for coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jackson for that. Read the documentation here:

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome

Answer (score 0):

try [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), a Google JSON lib for java.

Answer (score 0):

I would just say use a JSON parser like GSON or Jackson, the thing is by doing that you'll have to receive the entire String and parse it by hand each time (pain!).

If it's possible, I'd definitely look at using SpringMVC as by including Jackson in your servlet-context.xml you can actually pass the entire object through without doing any parsing by hand.

So you could declare a dumb object of `Plan` in Java and it will parse without you having to actually write any code intermediately to interpret the JSON string into an object.